# How to print unique elements after common elements using java

Tags: java

> I have two list of data one list contain only id, and second list
> contains all the details of those id, but second list contain many
> other id details that not present in first list, I want to store all
> the id details to create a third list as per list one then after store
> remaining id details. but I tried many time i am not able to store
> remaining id details in third list. Here below my code what I tried to
> solve this issue.
> StoreDragData.java

```
package task;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StoreDragData {
    private int id;

    StoreDragData() {
    }

    public StoreDragData(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<StoreDragData> demo() {
        List<StoreDragData> ll = new ArrayList<>();
        ll.add(new StoreDragData(6));
        ll.add(new StoreDragData(4));
        ll.add(new StoreDragData(7));
        ll.add(new StoreDragData(1));
        ll.add(new StoreDragData(5));
        ll.add(new StoreDragData(2));
        ll.add(new StoreDragData(3));


        return ll;
    }


}
```

> ServerList.java

```
package task;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServerList {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String subject;

    ServerList() {
    }

    public ServerList(int id, String name, String subject) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }


    public static List<ServerList> addStudentDetails() {
        List<ServerList> lls = new ArrayList<>();
        lls.add(new ServerList(1, "alex", "Math"));
        lls.add(new ServerList(2, "andrew", "Physic"));
        lls.add(new ServerList(3, "alok", "Chemistry"));
        lls.add(new ServerList(4, "Boby", "Botany"));
        lls.add(new ServerList(5, "Soumya", "Zoology"));
        lls.add(new ServerList(6, "Rwitik", "Ornithology"));
        lls.add(new ServerList(7, "Bikash", "Behavior of Money"));
        lls.add(new ServerList(8, "Sipun", "Economy"));
        lls.add(new ServerList(9, "Suresh", "CS"));



        return lls;
    }
}
```

BigTask.java

```
package task;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Bigtask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StoreDragData sdd = new StoreDragData();
        System.out.print(" Student id record");
        sdd.demo();
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        for (StoreDragData st:sdd.demo()){
            System.out.println(st.getId() );
        }
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        ServerList std = new ServerList();
        System.out.println(" Student  record details");
        ServerList.addStudentDetails();
        for (ServerList st : ServerList.addStudentDetails()) {
            System.out.println(st.getId() + " " + st.getName() + " " + st.getSubject());
        }
        System.out.println("=========================");
        System.out.println(" Final Result ");

        searchData(sdd.demo(), ServerList.addStudentDetails());
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        remainingRecord(std);
    }

    static void searchData(List<StoreDragData> userList, List<ServerList> studentList) {
        List<ServerList> finalList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
            Integer existIndex = isDataExist(userList.get(i).getId());
            if (existIndex != -1) {
                finalList.add(studentList.get(existIndex));
            }
        }

       /**print final list*/
        for (ServerList st : finalList) {
            System.out.println(st.getId() + " " + st.getName() + " " + st.getSubject());
        }

    }

    static Integer isDataExist(Integer id) {
        List<ServerList> list = (new ServerList()).addStudentDetails();

        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getId() == id) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
    static ServerList remainingRecord(ServerList std){
        List<ServerList> finalList = (new ServerList()).addStudentDetails();//final list
        //Student details list
        for (ServerList sls : finalList){
            if (!finalList.contains(sls)){
                System.out.println("Hai Iam unique");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Hai Iam  duplicate");
            }
        }
        return std;
    }
    static void search(){}

    /**Function for check exist id*/
    public Integer isExistIdInFinalList(Integer id){
        List<ServerList>  findList = (List<ServerList>) new ServerList();
        int index=-1;
        for (int i=0;i< findList.size();i++){
           if(findList.get(i).getId() == id){
               index =i;
               break;
           }
        }
        return index;
    }


}
```

> Output of my code is

```
 Student id record=========================================
6
4
7
1
5
2
3
=========================================
 Student  record details
1 alex Math
2 andrew Physic
3 alok Chemistry
4 Boby Botany
5 Soumya Zoology
6 Rwitik Ornithology
7 Bikash Behavior of Money
8 Sipun Economy
9 Suresh CS
=========================
 Final Result 
6 Rwitik Ornithology
4 Boby Botany
7 Bikash Behavior of Money
1 alex Math
5 Soumya Zoology
2 andrew Physic
3 alok Chemistry
---------------------------
```

> I get the result in final list  as per student id list one , but I
> miss the id 7,8,9 details in final list. First I want to store id
> details records as per  list one in final result then store remaining
> items. how can I do it.